# Input in a messageDialog box [HTML / Javascript]

Tags: javascript, windows, microsoft-metro

my question is simply how to put an input in a MessageDialog (Textbox ...). Here is the code for a button:

```
var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("<div>lol</div>", "Updates available");
enter code here

msg.commands.append(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Don't install", function (command) {
WinJS.log && WinJS.log("The 'Don't install' command has been selected.", "sample", "status");}));

msg.defaultCommandIndex = 1;
msg.showAsync();
```

Comment: added microsoft-metro tag. you should do that in future aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just update your MessageDialog to include a text box like so?

```
    var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("<div>lol<br/><input type="text"/></div>", "Updates available");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, it displays the code in the MessageDialog not the textbox